# Where are my generic shorts/skirt?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

When I started the game, I was given a shirt but no pants, so the game provided me with a dark skirt. I made the mistake of purchasing ugly shorts, but once I equipped them, I had no option for taking them off:

[image: take off your rainbow plaid shorts and j]

Is there any way to get back my generic pants before I purchased this abomination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to take off the shorts by putting on a dress (e.g., the one given for logging in on three different days) and then putting on my original sweater, which automatically applied my original leg coverings (shorts/skirt).

[image: skirt]